# Bootstrap Dropdown dynamic ajax list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap Dropdown and i'm trying to fill list items dynamically via AJAX before dropdown shown. My script must get available items from database and insert them into <ul></ul>

I prevents default event, do ajax and make a trigger after, but **"data" is undefined** and I don't see dropdown. Script like this usually works with forms properly.

```
    $(".dropdown").on("show.bs.dropdown", function(e, data){
    ths = $(this);
    if (data == 'okay') return true;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/core/test.php',
        data: 'test'
    }).done(function(response) {
        $(ths).children('ul').html(response);
        $(ths).trigger('click.bs.dropdown', 'okay');
    });

});
```

html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <a data-toggle="dropdown" 
      class="btn dropdown-toggle">My list <b class="caret"></b>
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      ...data from ajax puts here...
   </ul>
</div>
```

How can I fix it? Thanx.

Comment: does dropdown have `data` parameter along with event ? I dont think it has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap events doesn't pass arguments and in your code you expect both `e` and `data`.
You should check if the `ul` already has children and if it doesn't fetch some and append them.